# How to use function getstate() of the Google Motionchart in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, google-visualization, googlevis

I search a little and it seems that the API from google Motionchart does not allow to customize tooltips and so on. But I think there could be a way using getstate() to retrieve the information in a table and then use the selected items to create the interactive buttons that I am not able to do in the tooltips directly.

The documentation of getstate is available at: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#getstate

I review the documentation of googleVis package, but there were not information. So my question is there is a way to use this getdata capability in R?.

Thanks in advance.

This would be the structure of the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(googleVis)
library(RJSONIO)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage( 
    column(width=7,
            htmlOutput("Plot_Fruits"),
            actionButton("Current", label = "Get current fruits")),
    column(width=5, dataTableOutput('Current_Fruits')
               )),
server = function(input, output) {

    output$Plot_Fruits <- renderGvis({
        FinalPlot <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year") 
        FinalPlot
    })

    observe(input$Current,{}
        #Here use the getState() as it is explained at: 
        #https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#getstate
        #To update myState dynamically and render the table appropiately
    )

    output$Current_Fruits <- renderDataTable({
        #myState should be updated dynamically when the button is pressed. 
        myState <- '
        {"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"yLambda":1,
        "xZoomedDataMin":71,"nonSelectedAlpha":0,
        "dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"xZoomedDataMax":91,
        "iconType":"BUBBLE","duration":{"timeUnit":"Y","multiplier":1},
        "playDuration":15000,"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xLambda":1,
        "yZoomedDataMax":91,"yAxisOption":"4","xZoomedIn":false,
        "xAxisOption":"4","iconKeySettings":[{"trailStart":"2010",
        "key":{"dim0":"Apples"}},{"trailStart":"2010",
        "key":{"dim0":"Oranges"}}],
        "yZoomedDataMin":71,"time":"2010","yZoomedIn":false,
        "orderedByY":false,"colorOption":"2","showTrails":true,"orderedByX":false}
        '
        json_file <- fromJSON(myState)
        json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
            x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
            unlist(x)
        })
        Current_F <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", json_file),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

        datatable(Current_F,escape = FALSE, rownames = TRUE,
                  selection = 'single')
    })



}
```

)